# Can you get the pass or fail status of a test step with the Azure DevOps rest api?

Tags: rest, testing, azure-devops

I am writing an application that monitors the status of a test plan run.

Given a plan and a suite id I've been able to get a lot of information. For instance I can see the overall status of the test point and know if it is ready/in progress/complete, etc. but I want to go a step deeper on steps that are in progress.

I've been unable to get to the level of seeing what the status is of the steps in a test point (i.e. pass/fail, etc.). Is there a rest API call to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you get the pass or fail status of a test step with the Azure DevOps rest api?

Yes, you can get it through Rest API.

You could try to use this Rest API: [Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the Test Result. And the result contains the test step status.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=iterations&api-version=5.1
```

**Note:** You need to add parameters(`detailsToInclude=iterations`) to get the status of test steps

**Result:**

You could check the  **iterationDetails**(The status of the overall test steps) and **actionResults** (The status of each test step) in the API Response.

[image]